# WPF accessing UI element from another class Best Practices

Tags: wpf

In my current code I pass the UI elements I need to update to a central class that is retriving data and runs diffrent threads. In this class I then update the UI via a Dispatcher. My question would be if this falls under Best Practices and if not how would I best notify the main thread that new data and the UI is need of updating?

Comment: That is certainly not a good practice. Take a look at the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to use [data binding in WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to keep the controls updated and synced with the data.